# react-sound - Force React Component to update and go to position?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, react-native, components

I am trying to build an audio player using [react-sound.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sound) I want to implement a feature which simply goes back to a certain position in the audio.

I simply do this for now:

```
goToVeryCustomPosition() {
  this.setState({playFromPosition: this.state.myVeryCustomPosition});
}
```

My problem is this: This works -but it only works **once**. The sound will go back to the position specified, but if I want to do this two times in a row, it won't work.

I guess this is because my component is not updated since the position is still the same. When I set it first, it changes from position 0 (in the constructor), to position 233 (or whatever it might be). When I then call the thing again, it will still be 233, since this is what I want to do. But since this is the same as the previous state, React won't update. How could I solve this?

edit: the rest of the component.

constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
       playStatus: Sound.status.STOPPED,
       elapsed: 0,
       total: 0,
       playFromPosition: 0,
       myVeryCustomPosition: 1337.727
     }
  }
```

render & handleSongPlaying:

```
handleSongPlaying(audio){
     this.setState({
                      position: audio.position,
                      elapsed: audio.position,
                      total: audio.duration})
   }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row handle">
        <Sound
            url="./sound.mp3"
            playStatus={this.state.playStatus}
            onPlaying={this.handleSongPlaying.bind(this)}
            playFromPosition={this.state.playFromPosition}
            />

        <button onClick={this.togglePlay.bind(this)}>Play / Pause</button>
        <button onClick={this.repeat.bind(this)}>Replay</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show the rest of your component, especially the part where you set `this.state.myVeryCustomPosition`

Comment: why might this be important? I edited everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `forceUpdate`

```
goToVeryCustomPosition() {
    if(this.state.playFromPosition != this.state.myVeryCustomPosition) {
        this.setState({playFromPosition: this.state.myVeryCustomPosition});
    } else {
        this.forceUpdate()
    }
}
```

One more thing you can do is have a separate `state` variable like `isUpdating`. Where you set the `this.state.myVeryCustomPosition` set `isUpdating` to `true` and in the `goToVeryCustomPosition` set it to `false`.

This way it will always update and you will not have to use `forceUpdate` which is slightly frowned upon.

Comment: thanks. `forceUpdate` does not seem to work though, it does not make a difference. Would maybe need to somehow update the `<Sound>` component? Right now, with your solution, I update the higher order component which contains the `<Sound>` component. I am not sure what else it might be.

Comment: You can try doing that. Make a separate `state` variable like the `isUpdating` and pass it as a `prop` to the `Sound` component and in the `Sound` component check if the `isUpdating` prop has changed in the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method and when it does trigger a re-render using `forceUpdate`.

Comment: How would I go into the sound component? It's a npm module, not sure how I can modify this, also not sure whether I should?

Comment: Aah ok it's an external plugin. The `forceUpdate` should re-render the child components anyway. Could you change the `state` to something like 1337.7270 or something on the second attempt? It is a bit of a hacky method but that might trigger the change.